# Sum of Xn = X1+X2+X3... Xn probability density function using convolution

Tags: probability, convolution, density-function

I am currently struggling to find the full function of the sum of a large number of probabiliy density function (PDF) for random variable. All I find online corresponds to the sum of two variables being:

$$ 
f_{X_1+X_2}\left(x_3\right)=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{f_{X_1}({x_3-x}_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)}dx_2\
$$

I also find some examples with more than two variables, but either using binomial or normal distribution.So what is the general function for
$$
f_{X_1+X_2+X_3...X_N}\left(x_N\right) = ?
$$

I've derived a potential answer with this equation below. t
$$
f_{X_N}\left(x_n\right)=\int{\int{\int{\dots \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\prod^N_n{f_{X_{n+1}}\left(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right)}dx_{n+2}}}}}\
$$

Looking at it, I'm almost certain that this is completely wrong. Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: The first convolution should be $\int f_{X_1}(x_1-x_2)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_2$, having two variables $x_1$, and $x_3$ does not make sense as then $f_{X_1+X_2}$ would be a function of two variables $x_1,x_3$

Comment: Ok I see what you mean - I forgot to add that $$  X_3  = X_2+X_2 $$ Does the first equation makes more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so to answer my own answer using the help of [@mathreadler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213607/mathreadler), this is what I derived:

f and g are two probability distributions satisfying. Assuming f is a probability density function and F is its representative in the frequency domain. Fourier transform of f is

$$
\mathrm{f}\left(\mathrm{x}\right)\mathrm{=\ }\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu }\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}}
$$
and the inverse fourier transform is 
$$
\mathrm{F(}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{)}\mathrm{=\ }\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{f\left(\mathrm{x}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{-}\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{x}}\
$$
The sum of the distribution $\mathit{\Gamma}$ is defined as the convolution of the of the two distribution so that: 
$$
(f*g)(x)=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')f\ (x\ -\ x}\mathrm{')}\mathrm{dx'}}
$$
$$
=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu }\mathrm{(}\mathrm{x}\mathrm{-}{\mathrm{x}}^{\mathrm{'}}\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu }}\mathrm{dx'}} 
$$
$$
=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)\frac{{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}}{{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}{\mathrm{x}}^{\mathrm{'}}}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}}\mathrm{dx'}}
$$
$$
=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{-}\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}{\mathrm{x}}^{\mathrm{'}}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}}\mathrm{dx'}} 
$$
$$
=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{-}\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}{\mathrm{x}}^{\mathrm{'}}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}}\mathrm{dx'}} 
$$
$$
=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{g(x\ ')}{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{-}\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}{\mathrm{x}}^{\mathrm{'}}}\mathrm{dx'}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}}} 
$$
$$
\left(f*g\right)\left(x\right)=\ \int^{\infty }_{-\infty }{G\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)\mathrm{F}\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right){\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{2}\mathrm{\pi }\mathrm{i}\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{x}}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{\nu}} 
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}(f*g)(x))=G(\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{)}F(\mathrm{\nu}\mathrm{)} 
$$

${\mathcal{F}}^{-1}$ being the inverse Fourier transform:
$$
\left(f*g\right)\left(x\right)={\mathcal{F}}^{-1}(G\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)F\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)) 
$$

So basically, get the two distribution f and g, calculate their Fourier transform. Multiply them together and get the inverse Fourier transform to get $f*g$.
$$
\left(f_1*f_2*f_3\dots f_N\right)\left(x\right)=\ {{\mathcal{F}}^{-1}(F}_1\left(\mathrm{\nu }\right)F_2\left(\mathrm{\nu }\right)F_3\left(\mathrm{\nu }\right)\dots F_N\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)) 
$$
$$
\left(f_1*f_2*f_3\dots f_N\right)\left(x\right)=\ {\mathcal{F}}^{-1}\left(\prod^N_{n=1}{F_N\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)}\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid integrals and reduce the calculations to an elementwise product if you turn the convolutions into products by using the **Fourier transform** of each density function and combine with the convolution theorem.

---

But if you just want to use the definition with convolutions then at least you can use the result that the convolutional product is *commutative*, but it will still be kind of convoluted to work with and try and simplify.

Comment: Alright, I think I understood what you're saying. Calculate the FT of f and g, convolve it, and inverse fourier transform afterwards. This is what I got:
$$
\left(f_1*f_2*f_3\dots f_N\right)\left(x\right)=\ {\mathcal{F}}^{-1}\left(\prod^N_{n=1}{F_N\left(\mathrm{\nu}\right)}\right) 
$$

Comment: @Vinci: Yep, that is probably the easiest way that I know of. It gets kind of convoluted otherwise.